# Let $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Which of the following are sufficient conditions for $f$ to have a fixed point in $[0, 1]$?

Tags: functions, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

(a) $f(0)=f(1)$

(b)$f(1)<0<f(0)$

(c) $0<f(1)<f(0)$

(d) $f(0)<0<1<f(1)$

To obtain a fixed point, we should find $x=f(x)$ but how do I obtain the necessary conditions? What concept do I lack to begin solving this?

Comment: (a) You can take the function $f(x)=2$ for $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)=x+1$ for $x>1$ and $f(x)=x+2$ for $x<0$.

Comment: (c) You can take $f(x)=3-x$ for $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)=x+1$ for $x>1$ and $f(x)=x+3$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) on $f(x)-x$ which is also continuous.